# Calcular tabela sql em android

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Tenho a seguinte base dados sqlite e funciona bem:

```
db=openOrCreateDatabase("BaseDadosDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabeladados(data date,total real,descricao VARCHAR);");
```

Pretendo retornar a soma da tabela total entre datas.

Neste momento tenho a funcionar a pesquisa entre datas, pretendo o mesmo, mas agora a somar o total.

Código:

```
if(view==btnVer) {
    if (data.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
        alert("Erro data inicial", "Tem que inserir uma data para iniciar a pesquisa");
        return;
    }
    if (dataa.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
        alert("Erro data final", "Tem que inserir uma data para iniciar a pesquisa");
        return;
    }


    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from tabeladados WHERE data BETWEEN '"+data.getText()+"' AND '"+ dataa.getText()+"' ORDER BY data DESC", null);
    if(c.getCount()==0) {
        alert("Erro!", "Sem resultados entre as datas " + data.getText()+" E "+dataa.getText());
        return;
    }

    StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
    while(c.moveToNext())
    {

        buffer.append("Data:"+c.getString(0)+"\n");
        buffer.append("Total Horas: "+c.getString(1)+"\n");
        buffer.append("Descricão: "+c.getString(2)+"\n\n");
    }
    alert("Registos da data "+data.getText()+" A " + dataa.getText(), buffer.toString());    

}
```

O que pretendo é retornar uma soma e mostrar no ecrã ao pressionar um botão por exemplo. Ou seja ao pressionar o botão soma todos os campos da tabela total. `Valor1+valor2+valor`.

Comment: Bem o que pretendo é retornar uma soma e mostrar no ecrã ao pressionar um botão por exemplo.
Ou seja ao pressionar o botão soma todos os campos da tabela total. Valor1+valor2+valor

Comment: Boas aqui está o código: http://35.167.140.166/site/codigo.txt  Pretendo que ao pressionar o botão ver, seja possivel obter o total da tabela "total" ou seja somar todos os valores que la forem inseridos e mostrar uma mensagem de ecrã com a soma.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
"SELECT sum(total) as GrandTotal from tabeladados WHERE data BETWEEN '"+data.getText()+"' AND '"+ dataa.getText()+"' ORDER BY data DESC"
```

Como modelo do SQL. A seguir, como ficaria o codigo:

```
Double grandTotal;
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from tabeladados WHERE data BETWEEN '"+data.getText()+"' AND '"+ dataa.getText()+"' ORDER BY data DESC", null);
    if(c.getCount()==0) {
        alert("Erro!", "Sem resultados entre as datas " + data.getText()+" E "+dataa.getText());
        return;
    }

    StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
    while(c.moveToNext())
    {

        buffer.append("Data:"+c.getString(0)+"\n");
        buffer.append("Total Horas: "+c.getString(1)+"\n");
        buffer.append("Descricão: "+c.getString(2)+"\n\n");
    }
    alert("Registos da data "+data.getText()+" A " + dataa.getText(), buffer.toString());
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT sum(total) as GrandTotal from tabeladados WHERE data BETWEEN '"+data.getText()+"' AND '"+ dataa.getText()+"' ORDER BY data DESC", null); 
if(cur.moveToFirst()) { 
    grandTotal = cur.getDouble(0); 
}
alert("Total: "+ String.valueOf(grandTotal);
```

Comment: Query its nice now, and how show? :/

Comment: A query não dá erro, agora não consigo mostrar, como mostro? !!

Comment: Muito obrigado! Agora diz que o "grandtotal" nao foi inicializado que devo fazer?